# Css Font and Float issue on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, css-float

Hi thanks for your time i found totally wired issue.

I am working on site `"http://powerpitch-agency.com/dev/"`. it has logo in header on left side so when i am apply body to `"font-family :'helvetica_neue';"` Logo will goes above automatically. and it's only happening in chrome all other browser are ok. you can debug this by inspect element if you comment `font-family :'helvetica_neue` this line it will again fine

Comment: Please provide code to replicate the issue in your question, when the link expires this question will have little of value to other users that experience the same problem. Browsers do display fonts differently from each other, it sounds like Chrome takes up a bit more horizontal space in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`font-family: Helvetica Neue;`

Comment: Not i can't use it i have made my custom font-face please check style.css from source

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is a mistake, could you try to use correct font-family:

```
font-family: Helvetica Neue;
```

Comment: how does this add anything to the answer that was provided 6 minutes ago?

Comment: Not i can't use it i have made my custom font-face please check style.css from source